# Non recursive BST (binary search tree)

Tags: binary-search-tree

Hello I don't know what is wrong with my BST insert  method.
Any suggestions it has too be non recursive it adds to the right always I want to know why it adds to the ends to the BST when I print it shows that the nodes were added at the right only.

```
void InsertBST(LZWCmp cmp, TreeNode **root, int code) 
{
    TreeNode tmp = *root;
    TreeNode current = NULL;
    Code temp;
    Code temp1;
    int size;

    int comp;
    int direction = -1;
    if(*root == NULL)
        root = CreateNode(code)
    while(tmp != NULL) {
        temp = GetCode(cmp->cst, tmp->cNum);   
        temp1 = GetCode(cmp->cst, code);
        size = temp.size;
        if(temp1.size < temp.size)
            size = temp1.size;  
        comp = memcmp(temp1.data, temp.data, size);
        if(temp1.size < temp.size && comp == 0)
            comp = -1;
        else if(temp1.size < temp.size && comp == 0)
            comp = 1;
        if(comp < 0) {
            current = tmp;
            direction = FALSE;
            tmp = tmp->left;
        } else (
            current = tmp;
            direction = TRUE;
            tmp = tmp->right;
        }
    }

    if(direction == FALSE)
        current->left = CreateNode(code);
    else
        current->right = CreateNode(code);
}
```

Comment: `root = CreateNode(code)` should probably be `*root = CreateNode(code);` (note the semicolon)  Also: remove the variable tmp, and replace all its occurances by *root.

Comment: yeah it is  but still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
void InsertBST(LZWCmp cmp, TreeNode **root, int code)
{
    Code temp;
    Code temp1;
    int size;
    int comp;
    while ( *root ) {
        temp = GetCode(cmp->cst, (*root)->cNum);
        temp1 = GetCode(cmp->cst, code);
        size = (temp1.size < temp.size) ? temp1.size  : temp.size;
        comp = memcmp(temp1.data, temp.data, size);
        if (comp ==0 ) comp = (temp1.size < temp.size ) ? -1 : 1;
        root = (comp < 0) ?  &(*root)->left
                          :  &(*root)->right;
        }

    *root = CreateNode(code);

}
```

NOTE: this code does not check for duplicates. It always inserts a node.

NOTE2: I am not sure about the sign in: `if (comp ==0 ) comp = (temp1.size < temp.size ) ? -1 : 1;` (in the original the sign was the same in both cases)

Comment: Thanks thats new for me the &(*root)

Comment: Note: `&(*root)->left` : the `->` binds tighter than the `&` so the address-of-operator refers to the `left` field. The parentheses are needed because `->` binds even tighter than the `*` dereference-operator. Inorder-traversal is totally unrelated.